# How do I have my object execute internal code when Hibernate saves it?

Tags: java, hibernate

The following code saves `objA`.

```
A objA = new A();
session.save(objA);
```

When `session.save(A)` is called, I want my `A` Object to execute an internal method/function:

```
onSave() {
  this.b = some code;
}
```

Where can I put the code? Is there an actual `onSave()` method, or an interface to implement or abstract class to extend?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Hibernate interceptor `org.hibernate.Interceptor` and its `onSave` [method](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html)

```
boolean onSave(
    Object entity, 
    Serializable id, 
    Object[] state, 
    String[] propertyNames, 
    Type[] types)
```

Comment: This is also in the official Hibernate API: [`org.hibernate.Interceptor`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html). What you're referring to is a really old version of Hibernate. (Ah, you've edited your answer).

Comment: Is onSave() called everytime I called session.save(obj)? But I want it to be called only when an obj of class A is saved. In php or python, there's a handy way that you just write an override method in class A.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an [`Interceptor`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html).